# A unitary matrix $U$ transforms a basis $B$ into another basis $C$. Is $U^{-1}$ the basis change matrix from $B$ to $C$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have conjectured what I've specified in the question title. I'll re-specify in more detail:

Let $B$ be a basis, and $U$ a unitary matrix. Define $C$ as the basis where $\forall \vec{b_i} \in B,~\vec{c_i} = U\vec{b_i}$. Let $D$ be the basis change matrix from $B$ to $C$. Is $U^{-1} = D$?

I'm able to give an informal argument, but I suspect that it may be lacking somewhere and I haven't been able to come up with a formal proof.

I want to verify if the conjecture is correct or not with proof or counter example.

#### Informal Argument

Let $D$ be the basis change matrix from $B$ to $C$. $D^{-1}$ is then the basis change matrix from $C$ to $B$.

$D^{-1}$ maps a basis vector $\vec{c_i} \in C$ to a linear combination of vectors in $B$.

$U$ maps a basis vector $\vec{b_i} \in B$ to a linear combination of vectors in $B$ itself.

For $\vec{b_i} \in B$, $$U\vec{b_i} = \vec{c_i} = D^{-1}\vec{c_i} \tag{first equality by defintion}$$

$\therefore U$ should be equal to $D^{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

If $c_i=Ub_i$, then the change of basis matrix from $B$ to $C$ is indeed $U^{-1}$.

Try using the fact that any unitary matrix can be viewed as the change of basis from the basis consisting of its columns to the standard basis.